# Каким образом понять, что игрок перепрыгнул предмет/врага?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Делаю учебный проект по типу runner, игрок находится постоянно в режиме бега, ему навстречу движутся предметы которые ему необходимо перепрыгнуть. Столкнулся с трудностями, не могу разобраться, каким образом понять, что игрок перепрыгнул предмет/врага ? Какие есть варианты ? Если кто знает, поделитесь, пожалуйста информацией как такое реализуют, спасибо.

Конечная цель: хочу увеличить счет игрока после того как он перепрыгнет врага/предмет.

Сейчас у меня работает так: игрок по факту стоит на месте к нему прикручена анимация бега, прыжка, столкновении. К фону добавлен rigidbody2d и collider2d, чтобы создать эффект движения - я двигаю фон. Предмет/враг, которого необходимо перепрыгнуть имеет также rigidbody2d и collider2d, при движении фона он приближается к игроку т.е. предмет по факту не двигаю.

Видео https://monosnap.com/file/Xa0oBE8oGvKixs2TJAZOZp3BfKz3H5

Comment: Если у вас при движении, двигается только фон, то каким образом предмет/враг приближается к главному герою? Или он двигается вместе с фоном?

Comment: Да, т.к. он лежит на фоне

Comment: Может я вообще не верный подход выбрал ?

Comment: В принципе подход нормальный. Он экономит ресурсы и для такой игры больше и не надо. Для вашего вопроса, ну как вариант сделать просто стенку тригера перед персонажем, и каждый раз, когда за неё заходит противник, добавлять очки. Ваш фон будет двигаться, а тригер стоять рядом с персонажем статично, и просто проверять на вход противников в этот тригер.

Comment: спасибо, хотел так сделать, здесь получается мне стенку нужно отдельно двигать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае можно поставить невидимую стенку-тригер за персонажем. Она будет стоять неподвижно, и добавлять очки, когда прошёл враг. Таким образом если враг не дошел до стенки, это значит что он ударился об главного героя, и счёт не добавляется. А если прошёл, то герой успешно перепрыгнул, и получил очки. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точно, спасибо, это как раз избавит меня от перемещения самой стенки